# cx_Oracle SessionPool.acquire not waiting as expected

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to use `cx_Oracle.SessionPool` where the number of queries is potentially greater than the number of available connections. What I want to happen is for any calls to `acquire()` to wait until a connection becomes available. From the documentation[1], using a Get Mode of `cx_Oracle.SPOOL_ATTRVAL_WAIT` should mean that

> ...the caller should wait until a session is available if there are no free sessions available in the pool.

Calls however to `acquire()` where there are no available connections in the pool do not hang as I would expect, but instead I get the error `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-24399: invalid number of connections specified`.

A minimal example is as follows:

```py
poolSize = 4
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(
            user=user,
            password=password,
            dsn=dsn,
            min=poolSize,
            max=poolSize,
            increment=0,
            getmode=cx_Oracle.SPOOL_ATTRVAL_WAIT
        )

connections = []

for i in range(poolSize + 1):
    connections.append(pool.acquire())

>>> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-24399: invalid number of connections specified
```

My understanding from the quoted section of the documentation is that the final iteration of the loop should hang, rather than error. Is this not the case?

I have just updated to cx_Oracle version 8.3 from 8.2.1, with the same results on both.

[1] https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#sesspoolmodes

Comment: Your code works for me with 19c client libraries.  What is the version of the Oracle client libraries you are using?  I seem to recall seeing this error number with 12.2 client.   I don't recall the exact scenario.  Have you tried with different pool parameters, e.g. a non-zero increment?

Comment: This was the cause - due to other (temporary) constraints on my project I am using 11.2. Thank you - if you want to post this as an answer I'm happy to accept it.